# Querying MongoDB to return objects based on condition

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I am creating a very basic social media app which also allows a user to post a status. The Post model in the database has a field called 'private' which makes the posts private and only the friends of the user can view those.

I have an api endpoint that has an HTTP Get method and I want it to work like this:
return a requesting user's all public and private posts BUT return **only the public** posts of other users.

The following code achieves the above task but I am trying to get it done by a single query.

*Get all posts of the requesting user*
`const loggedInUserPosts = await Post.find({ user: req.user.id }).sort({ date: -1 });`

*Gets only public posts of other users*
`const otherUserPosts = await Post.find({ user: { $ne: req.user.id }, private: false }).sort({ date: -1 });`

The *user* key is a field inside Post model and has the value equal to whatever the user id is of the corresponding user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't really scale, as you're essentially going to be returning a lot of unnecessary posts as your social app grows, but it sounds like you're looking for the `$or` operator (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/)

So, something like this should work:

```
await Post.find( { $or: [ { user: req.user.id }, { user: { $ne: req.user.id }, private: false } ] } ).sort( { date: -1 } )
```

Comment: This is working like a charm. I do understand the problems this will bring as more posts will be added. I was just learning MongoDB so wanted to write brief and cleaner code to improve as I progress. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

Apply an OR condition looking for post belonging to the user or all the public post of other users

```
query={ 
  $or:[
      { user: req.user.Id },
      { user: { $ne: req.user.Id }, private: false }
  ]
}
Post.find(query)
```